# Password validation script won't return false to prevent form from submitting on submit

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm having a really weird issue and while I've looked at multiple other threads, none of the solutions posted worked. Basically I have a script that's supposed to validate a password and a confirm password field, shown below:

```js
function validatePasswords() {
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var password_confirm = document.getElementById("confirmPassword").value;
  var retval = true;

  if (password != password_confirm) {
    alert("Your passwords do not match.");
    document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
    document.getElementById("confirmPassword").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
    retval = false;
  }
  return retval;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bentham" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/images/icon.png" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate_passwords.js" async></script>
  <title>Create Account</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="my-itemizedForm" action="createAccount.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validatePasswords()" id="accountForm">
    <br>
    <p class="form-header">
      Enter your information below:
    </p>
    <div align="center">
      <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="EID" maxlength="10" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" minLength="2" maxlength="30" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" minLength="2" maxlength="30" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" minlength="10" maxlength="10" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" minLength="7" maxlength="40" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="Password" minLength="3" maxlength="40" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" minLength="3" maxlength="40" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input class="my-submitButton" type="submit" id="createAccount" value="Create Account">
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

I know that my script is linked to the document properly, as I have another script that, when given to onsubmit, stops the form from submitting:

```
function stop(){
    return false;
}
```

Why isn't my validation script working, given that stop() does? I'm new to javascript and relatively new to web development in general, so it may be a simple error but I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: are you re-using the password and confirmPassword id in any other form?

Comment: I just changed your example above into a runnable snippet with the HTML and JS combined...and it seems to work ok, would you agree? If it doesn't work in your real environment, then check for any differences, check for errors in the console which might stop the code from executing, etc. Is the code you've shown above the entire content of the page, or is there more in real life? P.S. Passwords should be in an [`<input type="password"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password) field to stop the password text from displaying on screen to any nosy onlookers.

Comment: The only thing I can see in the code (as shown) which might potentially be an issue in your real environment is the `async` in the `<script` tag. So maybe the script isn't loaded until it's too late. Any particular reason you added that? I doubt it's necessary. Try without it.

Comment: No, the only other HTML on the page is for header and footer elements, and they don't share any id's. Also as far as async goes I added it as I had read that it'll allow the page to load the HTML anyways if the javascript file is slow to load, probably not necessary for a tiny file like this but I figured it was good form. However, removing async does not fix the issue. Also the input type has been changed from text to password, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Any console errors, then? Is the JS file definitely loading (you can check your network tab). Have you tried adding console.log commands to check if the function is even firing? Or stepping through it with the JavaScript debugger? There is lots of investigation you can be doing.

Comment: Ok, it's throwing this at me: "jQuery requires a window with a document", though I'm not quite sure how to deal with it.

Comment: Are you even using jQuery for anything in your page?

Comment: Also it's a strange error...are you running this in some non browser environment? All Google results for that error are from ppl using react native and that kind of thing. (First thing you should do with an error you don't understand is Google it .. you're rarely the first person to have seen it)

Comment: Other than for bootstrap, no, there's nothing using it that should be affecting the script's execution as far as my knowledge goes.

Comment: If you don't need jQuery then remove it. Although anyway I can't see where you included it? And you didn't answer...what environment are you executing this in?

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I'm running this in Chrome. Also I figured it out, the solution is posted down below though I'm not sure why it works as opposed to everything else.

Answer (score 2):

I would sugget the following updates to your code, so that the `validatePasswords()` method is tied to your specific form instance, via the passed `event` object.

Additionally, I would update the password input elements to include class attributes so that you can select the input fields for the current form being validatd (rather than potentially select password input fields from elsewhere in the page).

Finally, you can also make use of the `preventDefault()` method on the `event` object to prevent form submit if the validation fails:

```js
function validatePasswords(event) {

  // Query password inputs via currentTarget (this form)
  var password = event.currentTarget.querySelector(".password").value;
  var password_confirm = event.currentTarget.querySelector(".confirmPassword").value;

  if (password != password_confirm) {
    alert("Your passwords do not match.");
    document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
    document.getElementById("confirmPassword").style.borderColor = "#E34234";

    // If validation fails, prevent submit
    event.preventDefault();
  }


}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bentham" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/images/icon.png" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate_passwords.js" async></script>
  <title>Create Account</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="my-itemizedForm" action="createAccount.php" method="post" onsubmit="validatePasswords(event)" id="accountForm">
    <br>
    <p class="form-header">
      Enter your information below:
    </p>
    <div align="center">
      <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="EID" maxlength="10" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" minLength="2" maxlength="30" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" minLength="2" maxlength="30" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" minlength="10" maxlength="10" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" minLength="7" maxlength="40" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <!-- Add class here -->
      <input type="password" id="password" class="password" placeholder="Password" minLength="3" maxlength="40" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <!-- Add class here -->
      <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" class="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" minLength="3" maxlength="40" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input class="my-submitButton" type="submit" id="createAccount" value="Create Account">
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Can I suggest also using proper password fields?

Comment: @ADyson great suggestion - thanks for that, just updated answer :-)

Comment: Thank you for the input. Unfortunately though this implementation isn't working either, I'm under the impression that the validation script isn't grabbing the values from the form for some reason, but then again even if I just hardcode it to always return false the form will still submit. It may be my development environment, as @ADyson suggested.

Comment: @TarekAllam you're welcome - just to confirm, what browser are you running this in? And, did you manage to confirm that the `js/validate_passwords.js` is actually loading? Perhaps you need to make this an abolute path? Ie, add a leading `/` like this? `/js/validate_passwords.js` ?

Comment: @Dacre Denny, I'm running this in Chrome. Also the absolute path doesn't work, though I've discovered that jQuery is acting up, it's throwing "jQuery requires a window with a document" at me right now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out, I'm not entirely sure why it works now but the issue was that I needed a name and an id tag on the password fields, like so:

```
<form class="my-itemizedForm" action="createAccount.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validatePasswords()" id="accountForm">
    <div class="createAccountField">
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" minLength="3" maxlength="40" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" minLength="3" maxlength="40" required>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <input class="my-submitButton" type="submit" name="createAccount" value="Create Account">
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the javascript I've got working:

```
function validatePasswords(){
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var password_confirm = document.getElementById("confirmPassword").value;

    if(password != password_confirm){
        alert("Your passwords do not match.");
        document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
        document.getElementById("confirmPassword").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    else{
    return true;
    }
}
```

If anybody has any idea why this implementation works as opposed to the others, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: You already had an id. The name attribute is certainly required in order for the field value to be submitted to the server (same is true of all your other fields as well), but I can't really see how it would be affecting the JavaScript. Anyway glad you got it working at least.